# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Using Jquery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to use Jquery Tabs here http://beta.biozymeinc.com/vitalize/products/vitalize-dog/. the "description" and "reviews" li tags should be the tabs. You can see it functioning fine here http://beta.biozymeinc.com/vitaferm/products/vita-charge-paste/

Details:

1. I'm using Wordpress Multi-Site.
2. It is working fine in other folders or "sites" using the exact same header.php file as far as the  is concerned. The only difference is some graphics below the
3. I tried using the style sheet and script as it is typed on the jquery tutorial and I still get the same error

Does anyone have an idea of why it would just "break"? I will keep reading and digging around trying to find an answer but I'm on a deadline to finish this tonight so I thought I would cast a wide net and hope for the best.

Comment: would bet good money you have jQuery being loaded more than once in page and last version loaded is wiping put plugins bound to prior versions

Comment: Agreed, are you expecting the version of jQuery to be the same in those two sites? Your broken page is actively running 1.7.2 while the working one is 1.10.2 I can see the include is for 1.10... You can check this in the console with: $.fn.jquery

Comment: Y'all were right. I guess I kept looking over it again and again. It was called again in the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As charlietfl pointed out You have included another version of jQuery in your page, look for:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your page source, remove it, problem should be solved.

Comment: Thanks. I think I just had dead head from looking at that for too long and missed it.